# How to retrieve the uid value using i2cget for the PN532?

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I want to read the values ​​of my registry using i2cget to retrieve the value of the UID of the tag but I always find 0x00. I work with an Odroid-XU4 terminal and the tagNFC I use is PN532. The communication protocol used is i2c. Need help

Comment: Haven't worked on that specific set up, but have you checked the values using logic analyser?

Comment: No i didn't check the values using logic analyser but I use libnfc library with Linux  it works very well ! But i didn't find the equivelence of this library on Android

Comment: Android != Linux, though you may use standart Linux kernel interfaces.